# Javascript: Play audio once in multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, audio, local-storage

In my application I programmed that the system **plays an audio** to notify the user when he received a notification.

If the user have a lot of browser tabs opened, this audio is played a lot of times (one for tab).

Is there any way to do that the audio **only plays once**?

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set a flag in `localStorage`:

```
//create random key variable
var randomKey = Math.random() * 10000;
//set key if it does not exist
if (localStorage.getItem("tabKey") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("tabKey", randomKey);
}
```

This way, the item `tabKey` will be set to the `randomKey` of the first tab. Now, when you play the audio, you can do:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("tabKey") === randomKey) {
    playAudio();
}
```

This will play the audio only in the first tab.

The only problem is, you have to react to the case, that the user is closing the first tab. You can do this by unsetting the `tabKey` item on tab close and catching this event in other tabs with the `storage` event:

```
//when main tab closes, remove item from localStorage
window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("tabKey") === randomKey) {
        localStorage.removeItem("tabKey");
    }
});

//when non-main tabs receive the "close" event,
//the first one will set the `tabKey` to its `randomKey`
window.addEventListener("storage", function(evt) {
    if (evt.key === "tabKey" && evt.newValue === null) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("tabKey") === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("tabKey", randomKey);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Only one question: How can I tell the other tabs that when the first tab is closed execute this piece of code? Thank you a lot!

Comment: And how to put tabKey in null again if the user close the first tab?

Comment: @AralRoca I updated my answer and included an example on how to do it.

Comment: This is a great solution but do you have a workaround for the issue when the first tab gets refreshed, as this generates a different randomKey, leaving you in the position of having no active tab